# Intermittent failure to grant correct ACLs

Tags: acl, debugging

We have a Drupal 9 site with approx 50 active users and some relatively complex ACLs (>100 rules). For the vast majority of users, all works fine but we have a very small number of users who it fails for - one user in particular is affected almost daily and a handful of others are affected every couple of weeks or so. It's triggered when the user logs in, and they cannot see a particular group of contacts. To 'fix' it, a colleague has to remove them from the group and re-add them - and then the correct access is restored. However, it's intermittent and doesn't happen every time.

We've got as far as identifying something in the error logs -

```
21267 (
21268     [callback] => Array
21269         (
21270             [0] => CRM_Core_Error
21271             [1] => exceptionHandler
21272         )
21273
21274     [code] => -3
21275     [message] => DB Error: constraint violation
21276     [mode] => 16
21277     [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache (user_id, contact_id, operation) SELECT 0 as user_id, contact_a.id as contact_id, 'View' as operation  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE     ( (
21278             `contact_a`.id IN (
21279                SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE group_id IN (154) AND status = 'Added'
21280
21281              )
21282           ) )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY contact_a.id [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d9`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_us      er_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
21283     [type] => DB_Error
21284     [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache (user_id, contact_id, operation) SELECT 0 as user_id, contact_a.id as contact_id, 'View' as operation  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE     ( (
21285             `contact_a`.id IN (
21286                SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE group_id IN (154) AND status = 'Added'
21287
21288              )
21289           ) )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY contact_a.id [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d9`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_us      er_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
21290     [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache (user_id, contact_id, operation) SELECT 0       as user_id, contact_a.id as contact_id, 'View' as operation  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a WHERE     ( (
21291             `contact_a`.id IN (
21292                SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact WHERE group_id IN (154) AND status = 'Added'
21293
21294              )
21295           ) )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY contact_a.id [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d9`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_us      er_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]"]
21296 )
21297
```

As well as `[debug] $API Request Authorization failed` at the same time. Can someone help me figure out where to look?

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: half an answer at best!*

> ```
> CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` 
> FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) 
> ON DELETE CASCADE
> ```

This suggests that the user_id value doesn't exist in the contact table.

And this makes sense because the user_id here is 0; and there will not be a contact with ID 0.

But I don't understand when or why `user_id` 0 specified?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, that's a good point! I'll do some more digging

Comment: (wonders if this has anything to do with it https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26627)